# Can't access JSON body in OKHTTP GET request

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, okhttp

```
fun fetchJson(){
        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics?country")
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "mykey")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com")
                .build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to fetch data")
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println(body)
            }
            
        })
    }
```

I'm trying to get some data from an API and display it in my app. In the given code, response?.body()?string() android studio highlights the body() part in red. I can't access the json data from the API. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use retrofit as it will be easy for you to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue comes from trying to call `body` as a function instead of as a variable? I don't generate any errors when I have the body line as:

`val body = response.body?.string()`

(For what it's worth, AS also said that the `?` on `response` was unnecessary).